# Vim exit Insert mode with some key press

Tags: vim

I have reassigned `;` to `:` in Vim. I am constantly saving my code using `:w`. When I am in the insert mode, after making some changes, due to my muscle memory, I type `;w` to save the document, but it adds `;w` text in the code. Is it possible to assign `;w` in insert mode to exit and save the document. If there is a better method, please let me know.

Comment: your question doesn't seem to be phrased properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:inoremap ;w <esc>:w<cr>i` save buffer and return to insert mode
`:inoremap ;w <esc>:wq<cr>` save and close buffer (exit vim if buffer only one).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can remap `:` and `;` at the OS level, and just get used to it. I started that some months ago and the adjustment was fairly smooth. Now I love it. Not sure what OS you’re on, but I’m sure there’s a solution for any. In X, you’d use `xmodmap`. In my `~/.xinitrc` I have (among many remappings):

```
# Swap ; and :
xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = colon semicolon"
```

Use `xev` to see what exactly your keycodes are.